# Trying to save model in h5 (using keras and tensorflow) - unable to create link

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, h5py

> ***RuntimeError***: Traceback (most recent call
> last)  in ()
> 128 # Run experiments with the Shifted Patch Tokenization and Locality Self Attention modified ViT
> 129 vit_net = create_vit_classifier(vanilla=False)
> --> 130 vit_model = run_experiment(vit_net)
>
> 3 frames /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/h5py/_hl/group.py in
> **setitem**(self, name, obj)
> 371
> 372             if isinstance(obj, HLObject):
> --> 373                 h5o.link(obj.id, self.id, name, lcpl=lcpl, lapl=self._lapl)
> 374
> 375             elif isinstance(obj, SoftLink):
>
> h5py/_objects.pyx in h5py._objects.with_phil.wrapper()
>
> h5py/_objects.pyx in h5py._objects.with_phil.wrapper()
>
> h5py/h5o.pyx in h5py.h5o.link()
>
> ***RuntimeError: Unable to create link (name already exists)***

Comment: You are writing on a hdf5 file that already exists, you need to use a different filename.

Comment: @Dr.Snoopy there are no files that has the same name of this one, I deleted all the files in the directory but I still have this problem. I read online that could be a problem of variables name in the net, but isn't this problem neither!